# Twitter oAuth Connection issue

Tags: php, twitter, oauth

I am doing Login with twitter in my application and using Twitter `oAuth`. I am placing proper consumer key and proper consumer secret key and valid callback url still having a error

> Could not connect to Twitter. Refresh the page or try again later.

so what should I do now. couldn't trace out what is causing the trouble.

My index file

```
<?php

/**
 * User has successfully authenticated with Twitter. Access tokens saved to session and DB.
 */

/* Load required lib files. */
session_start();
require_once('oauth/twitteroauth.php');
require_once('twitter_class.php');

if(isset($_GET['connect']) && $_GET['connect'] == 'twitter'){
    $objTwitterApi = new TwitterLoginAPI;
    $return = $objTwitterApi->login_twitter($_GET['connect']);
    if($return['error']){
        echo $return['error'];
    }else{
        header('location:'.$return['url']);
        exit;
    }
    
}


?>
```

My callback.php

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once('oauth/twitteroauth.php');
require_once('twitter_class.php');
if (isset($_REQUEST['oauth_token']) && $_SESSION['oauth_token'] !== $_REQUEST['oauth_token']) {
  $_SESSION['oauth_status'] = 'oldtoken';
  header('Location: destroy.php');
}else{
    $objTwitterApi = new TwitterLoginAPI;
    $connection = $objTwitterApi->twitter_callback();
    if( $connection == 'connected'){
        header('Location: index.php?connected=Y');
        exit;
    }else{
        header('Location: index.php?connected=F');
        exit;
    }
}
```

Help me on this hence i am new to this couldn’t trace out the actual problem.

PS: in `oAuth` there is always a blank response if curl

Comment: give call back url in your app settings this  solved my problem

Comment: i have tried this as you said but still same error

Comment: is your server firewall blocking outgoing connections?

Comment: How can i check it please explain